# SELECT all from TABLE 1 where some condition NOT IN TABLE 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table 1: members

```
mem_id    mem_name
1         Name1
2         Name2
3         Name3
4         Name4
```

Table 2: swipes

```
swp_id    swp_by    swp_to
1         1         3
2         2         3
3         1         2
4         4         1
```

Here, member with `mem_id` 1 swiped members 2 and 3. So member id 1 must not see members 2 and 3 anymore. He must only see member 4 as its not yet swiped by him. Similarly, member 2 swiped member 3 so he must not see member 3 anymore but must see members 1 and 4.

My current query I tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM members
LEFT JOIN swipes ON members.mem_id = swipes.swp_to
WHERE mem_id != :mem AND swipes.swp_to IS NULL
```

This only solves "half" the problem. With this query I am able to get those users who are not yet swiped i.e., not yet in `swp_to` but I am not able to detect the user that is swiping. For example, when user 1 swiped user 2 and 3, this query detects that user 2 and 3 is swiped and hence are not shown again but they should not be shown only to user 1 and should still be shown to other users. Here, they aren't showing to anyone else.

I also tried adding `AND swp_by = mem_id` in the query but that seems not the correct thing to do as its isn't working either.

Comment: Which id do you use in place of `:mem` parameter?

Comment: use `not exists`

Comment: @El_Vanja that is the logged in user's (swiping user) id.. Not relevant here. Plz ignore it. It means that I am selecting all the members from members table except the user who is viewing them.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu can you show how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.* FROM members m
WHERE m.mem_id <> :mem
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1   
  FROM swipes
  WHERE swp_by = :mem AND swp_to = m.mem_id  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LdP79ZVKARfcm3PFpszkc/1).

Comment: Perfect... Exactly what I wanted. :D

Comment: However, does this method consume less resources? Will it explode for vast amount of users? Is this a good approach?

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of `SELECT 1` ? I never saw anyone use 1 here. Was that only for your experiment in demo? Should I write `*` or something else in place of 1 ?

Comment: All you have to do is try it. It is suited to your requirement if you want to get all the users that a specific user *can see*. Just set indexes to the queried columns.

Comment: That 1 could be 0 or null or *. It makes no difference. It's just my preference when I use EXISTS. All that is important is to check the existence of any row that satisfies the conditions inside the EXISTS subquery.

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap EXISTS basically ignores the SELECT portion of the query within it; it's just certain syntax rules require the query to actually have a SELECT; often `SELECT 1` is used to make it explicit that the original query author expected no specific data.

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap is there a reason that you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: @forpas please don't mind it. Your answer also worked perfect but as Uueerdo explained in his answer's comments that your answer has a sub query which would execute separately for every member (other than the :mem member) which can add up over thousands of members. And the last query he provided worked just like yours but with only 1 query. Hence, considering it lighter and less resource exhaustive, I went with it. Otherwise, your one was perfect too. For more on this, please check Uueerdo's comment about your answer in his accepted answer's comment section. I however, upvoted your answer :)

Comment: What you don't know maybe about EXISTS is that id does not scan the whole table. It returns as soon as it finds a row. Also what do you mean *execute separately for every member*? The condition `m.mem_id = s.swp_to AND s.swp_by = X` in the query that you prefer executes for every combination of rows of the 2 tables.

Comment: So in short your query is better than Uueerdo's? Is this what you are saying? Are you sure? I will go back and accept yours if its a yes.

Comment: Why? Because I say so? In a previous comment I said: *All you have to do is try it*. Try both and use the better one.

Comment: Right now both are giving equal result. How can I come to a conclusion? You guys are better expert in SQL than I am. You can surely recommend the better one in the long run out of the two. Uueerdo had his opinion that your one would work comparably fine but then he also gave a downside. You say which on of you both is better for long run?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I had not read that comment of Uuerdo. Just to put it in simple words its b & s. That *execute the subquery separately for every member* is true as it is true for his query. If the 1st table has M rows and the 2nd table has N rows then there will be MxN comparisons for the conditions: `m.mem_id = s.swp_to AND s.swp_by = X` and after that the results will be filtered for the conditions: `m.mem_id <> X AND s.swp_id IS NULL`. You can find many answers in SO that use correlated subqueries and not 1 but 2 or more EXISTS statements that perform better than any join.

Comment: That's why I asked you to read Uuerdo's statement about your query.

Comment: @forpas Calm down, it wasn't like I was saying your query was crap or anything, just giving my assessment based on my experience, after they specifically asked for it. I just ran some tests on dbfiddle _(not sure how to save/link them, and I know it isn't the most reliable to do a speed test, but whatever)_ and they perform about as I expected, run comparably. One is usually noticeably about 10% faster than the other when the number of members passes 16-32k, but which one actually seems to depend on which order `swp_by` and `swp_to` occupy in a composite key.

Comment: @Uueerdo when I was asked by the OP if my code is efficient I answered: *All you have to do is try it*. Did you do the same? No. You invented that a correlated subquery inside EXISTS would perform worst because it would execute for each row etc etc? But this is exactly what a join does too for every row of table1 to every row of table2. So while exists may return as soon as it finds a match a join will continue to scan the whole table for matches. This is what I had to explain to the OP. And still I don't say that my query would perform better. I say *All you have to do is try it*.

Comment: Calm down everyone! I just want to thank both of you for being so much helpful. Thanks both of you for investing so much effort in this topic. I really appreciate it. And @forpas thanks for saying "while exists may return as soon as it finds a match a join will continue to scan the whole table for matches". I was looking for this kind of theoretical difference between both. Now things are better clear :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you need a (almost) cartesian product of the members table, to get all possible combinations

```
SELECT m1.mem_id AS m1ID, m2.mem_id AS m2ID
FROM members AS m1 
INNER JOIN members AS m2 ON m1.mem_id != m2.mem_id
```

then, you use the swipes to eliminate rows already paired up.

```
SELECT m1.mem_id AS m1ID, m2.mem_id AS m2ID
FROM members AS m1 
INNER JOIN members AS m2 ON m1.mem_id != m2.mem_id
LEFT JOIN swipes AS s ON m1.mem_id = s.swp_by AND m2.mem_id = s.swp_to -- Find corresponding swipes
WHERE s.swp_id IS NULL -- Filter out anything that was swiped
;
```

WHERE conditions are "logically" applied after JOINs.

---

Alternatively, if you only want to see the members member X has not yet swiped....

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members AS m
WHERE m.mem_id <> X
  AND m.mem_id NOT IN (SELECT swp_to FROM swipes WHERE swp_by = X)
;
```

or

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN swipes AS s ON m.mem_id = s.swp_to AND s.swp_by = X
WHERE m.mem_id <> X AND s.swp_id IS NULL
;
```

With a large table, while the first option will give you all potential unswiped matched, it will "explode" with results; roughly M * (M-1) - S, where M = number of members and S = number of swipes. This version will just get potential matches on a member by member basis, but be much less resource intensive. Note: the last of these two is more likely to be able to take advantage of an index on `swipes(swp_by, swp_to)`.

Comment: Says "Unknown column 's.id' in WHERE clause..."

Comment: Fixed, I overlooked the id column was `swp_id`, and assumed it was just `id`; also just fixed some `id` instead of `mem_id` mistakes in the latter part just now.

Comment: Which one of all three do you recommend the most?

Comment: I'd tend toward the last one; it only involves a single join and is most likely to make good use of indexes. The number of swipes with swp_by = a specific mem_id will never exceed the number of members, and joining those on mem_id = swp_to will not yield an intermediate (internal) result set any larger either). The first version with a member count of 1000 can have an intermediate point where it has 999000 result row "candidates".

Comment: Answer by @forpas worked perfectly for me, do you think that will "explode" ? Do you recommend that method? Is that a good approach and consumes less resources according to you?

Comment: Forpas' is perfectly workable and will most likely perform comparably, but it uses a correlated subquery, which means it may internally execute the subquery separately for every member (other than the `:mem` member) which can add up over thousands of members; in my experience JOINs tend to be faster unless the outer query has very few intermediate results. _Some people tend to prefer correlated versions though; perhaps from working with data/queries that have such patterns._

Comment: Your last one also worked perfectly for me. I just had to replace `X` with `:mem`. And as you said JOIN is faster and better since its not using sub query and not creating extra thousands of records I will go with this one. :) Do you confirm that technically your last one is better than Forpas' ?

Comment: X wasn't meant literally, just as a generic placeholder. Which one is better is really dependent on the data itself, if you have few members and many swipes (or in scenarios where the match condition is more complicated costly), a correlated approach can be much faster; but presuming (swp_by, swp_to) pairs are unique (a mem can't swipe the same mem more than once), I would expect swipes to stay reasonably sized for this particular JOIN (since it is actually reduced by swp_by = X within the join).

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap to clarify; by "explode" I did not mean malfunction or break down. I meant the semi-Cartesian intermediate results would grow exponentially. 2 members -> 2 intermediate, 3 members -> 6 intermediate, 4 members -> 12 intermediate, 5 -> 20, etc.... 100 -> 9900 ...

Answer (score 3):

You can generate all pairs of members with (essentially) as `cross join`.  Then filter out the ones that have been swiped:

```
select m.mem_id, m2.mem_id
from members m join
     members m2
     on m.mem_id <> m2.mem_id left join
     swipes s
     on s.swp_by = m.mem_id and s.swp_to = m2.mem_id
where s.swp_by is not null;
```

Comment: Says "Unknown column 's2.swp_by' in WHERE clause..."

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap . . . That is a typo.  It should be `s.swp_by`.